# How to automize an UDS command by a CAPL script

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

For test automatization in my current project it is necessary to automize the sending of UDS commands with a simple CAPL script inside of CANoe. The possible UDS commands are given by a ODX file.

How can I write and execute such a CAPL script and how can I transform the UDS commands inside of the ODX file to the CAPL script.

I'm relatively new here in the automotive sector, so that my question might by a bit unspecific. Can someone give assistance and suggest some further readings.

Comment: What have you done so far? As a first step, I would suggest to take a look at the diagnostics demo-configurations coming with CANoe. There are plenty of examples for sendings requests, also using ODX-files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to configure the Diagnostics Console, using the Diagnostic/ISO TP Configuration. Provide it with a Diagnostic Description file, as well as a DLL containing the keys needed to enter the different sessions on the ECU.

[image]

After you have succesfully set default values, such as timing and ID messages for the requests and responses of the ECU, you can call the Diagnostic Services through the Diagnostic Console and CAPL.